# How do you return 2 or more duplicates in a multidimensional list

Tags: python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

I have a multidimensional list that I would like to return 2 or more duplicates but I don't know what code to use.

For example here is my list

```
A=[[a,b],[b,c],[g,i],[a,c],[a,b],[a,b],[b,c]]
```

I would like to return 2 or more duplicates in my list. So it would be something like this

```
b=[[a,b],[b,c]]
```

Comment: Could you share what you've tried? Are you looking for duplicate lists within the multidimensional list, or duplicate values across the whole collection?

Comment: For example here is my list A=[[a,b],[b,c],[g,i],[a,c],[a,b],[a,b],[b,c]]. I would like to return 2 or more duplicates in my list. So it would be something like this b=[[a,b],[b,c]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's built-in function `count()` to determine occurrences of an item in a list. To achieve what you're looking for, you can do something like the following:

```
a = [["a", "b"], ["b", "c"], ["g", "i"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "b"],["b", "c"]]

dupes = list()
for item in a:
    if a.count(item) > 1 and item not in dupes:
        dupes.append(item)

print(dupes)
>>> [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20counter#collections.Counter), converting the lists into tuples so they can be hashed (and then counted), and then filtering the counter based on the count being 2 or more:

```
from collections import Counter

A = [["a", "b"], ["b", "c"], ["g", "i"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "b"],["b", "c"]]

counts = Counter(map(tuple, A))
b = [list(t) for t, c in counts.items() if c > 1]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c']]
```

Comment: is there a way to get the max duplicates as well?

Comment: @outkast20 if you mean the most common value and its count you can use `counts.most_common(1)`

Comment: sorry.i probably didnt by accident

Comment: How do I put my list in counts.most_common(1)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Ok basically I do I use the code counts.most_common(1)

Comment: Just `print(counts.most_common(1)`. If you have follow-up questions, you really should ask the person whose answer you accepted.